# What kind of bike is this? Can anyone tell by the logo?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

I got this bike but am not sure what kind it is is there anyone who knows this logo on here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the first photo - looks like a hybrid bike, that is a rigid frame with no suspension.

The threadless steerer implies newer rather than older, but only within the last two decades.

I do not recognise the logo, but it is in a funny place.  Normally logos are found on the front of the head tube.  To be there is odd.   Is it a proper lug, or is it something else more decorative ?

Comment: It is a bmx bike I will load another pic of I can you could see it better

Comment: @Tyftsix Well isn't this a bit late to let slip that it's a BMX? Could you please edit the question to include all the information you already have about the bike?

Comment: It is obviously a BMX bike from the pic. Steel, BMX lever, BMX stem, gusset...

Comment: I thought it was some 700c singlespeed/fixed gear "project"